# ABI encoding params/values length mismatch usePrepareContractWrite

Tags: wagmi

I am using wagmi-react hooks to write contract data. Everything works fine with the `useContractWrite()` but have issues with `usePrepareContractWrite()`

> ABI encoding params/values length mismatch. Expected length (params):
> 2 Given length (values): 0

This is the abi I am using for ERC721 NFTs

```
import { erc721ABI } from "wagmi";
   
 export const ContractConfig = {
        address: '0x07a06AD39f940a505B306b294b29390e792C3869', 
        abi: erc721ABI
    }
```

This is the usePrepareContractWrite

```
 const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        ...ContractConfig,
        functionName: 'setApprovalForAll',
    });
```

This is useContractWrite

```
const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config);

if (write) {
            write({
                args: [BatchTransferAddress, true],
                from: address
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-setApprovalForAll-address-bool-) the `setApprovalForAll` method expects two arguments - `operator` and `approved` but it looks like you're not passing in the `args` property in your `usePrepareContractWrite` call.

That's why you're seeing the error `Expected length (params): 2 Given length (values): 0`

Comment: Perhaps you could include a code sample to demonstrate and provide more clarity to make this answer more clear.